# NSMutableArray caching failure

Tags: xcode, encoding, nsmutablearray

I would like to cache the result of some https request to speed up the user interface and so I wanted to cache the data in the applicationWillResignActive: and restore it in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
For doing so I am using the following code snippet:
    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

```
NSString* cachesDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString* archivePath=[cachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppCache/Paline.archive"];

NSLog(@"archivePath=%@ paline=%@", archivePath, detailViewController.palineArray);

BOOL success=[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:detailViewController.palineArray toFile:archivePath];

NSLog(@"%@",success?@"success": @"failure");
```

that fails and returns nil upon restore with:

```
 NSMutableArray* cachedItems=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:archivePath];
 NSLog(@"archivePath=%@ cache=%@", archivePath, cachedItems);
```

The palineArray is an NSMutableArray with values, when serialized as shown by the previous NSLog.
What could it be? Is it not NSMutableArray coding compliant or what?

Thanks,
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

Simply the example of the book I took the example from add an extraneous AppCache directory.